# How would one go about designing a linguistic tone in copywriting?

Tags: copywriting, culture, design-language

For example, a startup might have more of a conversational or playful tone, a law office might be more serious and straight to the point. Obviously this affects the users interpretation of the site. I was wondering if there are any specific methodologies that could help in determining what type of tone might be best for the target audience?

Comment: This seems to be much more suited for [writers.se] SE site. The question sounds less about user experience and design and more about how tone affects a reader and how to write for a particular audience.

Comment: For me this is well suited here. There are other questions here asking for tone like this one: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/63558/using-funny-error-messages-in-finance

Comment: If you are interested in how to decide on a tone, one could try simple focus group testing. If you want to learn to develop a tone, I think the best answer is "write a lot." :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A combination of your brand persona, the context of use of the material, and the emotional needs of your user persona can give you a sense of the appropriate tone.

Are you designing an **interface used on a mobile device on an oil rig** in the open ocean? Does "Ollie", your persona, need information about how to troubleshoot a safety problem?

- The tone might be businesslike, maybe even brusque and without preamble, and the content might be a checklist.

Are you designing the user experience for a **pregnancy test that will be distributed with Plan B**? Does your persona, "Paris", need to be reassured about the accuracy of the test, and want the information while under tremendous cognitive load?

- The tone might be reassuring, warm and comforting, while your content conveys factual information about efficacy rates.

Are you designing a **fantasy football app meant to be used stealthily on a phone at work**? Does your persona, "Frank", want to follow his team throughout the day, without anyone noticing?

- The tone of your alerts might be conspiratorial, and the visual design would be subtle or might mimic the look of a business app.

Comment: well explained :)

Comment: Great answer! This is a wonderful example of how personas should be used as well.