# How (and when) do you describe "affordance" in your Interaction Design?

Tags: interaction-design, affordance, documentation, mockup

Take the following example of an animation in a webstore.

[image: Selecting a whine will make it float and it will fly to your "bag" when clicked "add to cart"]

Say you have to write an Interaction Design document about this. I would imagine it would look something like this (VERY simplified of course):

---

**User-story**

*"As a customer, I can add a wine bottle to my cart, so I can buy it"*

**Use-case**:

1. Move the mouse over the wine bottle
2. Click the "Add to Cart" button
3. Result: Wine bottle is now in the "My bag" section

**Mock-up**

[image: Basic mock-up]

---

But where/when do I describe the fact that the bottle will float when the mouse hovers over it, and visually moves to the cart box when "add to cart" is clicked? I don't see it as part of the Story/Case/Mock-up at all.

Comment: Rewrite of https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/121592/how-do-you-describe-animation-effects-in-your-interaction-design-and-in-which since people seem to refuse to re-open it with the changes i made to it

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't add another section? Something like "Implementation Requirements", or "Interaction Details", etc. where you can detail specifics about how exactly things should work

Answer (score 1):

At my workplace the UX team has early reviews of the developers' work (during the code reviews) so we can comment on things like this. We also include a link to the mockup in the work item, either in a comment or in the list of requirements. And we discuss what's needed during our planning meetings when the items are picked up. So there are plenty of opportunities to convey the interaction requirements and check that they're done correctly.